# Django not loading the correct locale files

Tags: django, internationalization, django-1.8

I'm having a problem with Django loading the correct translation (.po/.mo) files.

I know my translations are working because when I change the LANGUAGE_CODE to 'fr' I can see my string translated.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('nl', 'Nederlands'),
    ('fr', 'Frans'),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True
```

But when I set my translations to use the `i18n_patterns` in `urls.py` it is not loading my French (fr) translations when I visit: `127.0.0.1:8000/fr/about/` it still loads the Dutch (nl) values.

Funny thing is when I visit `127.0.0.1:8000/fr/admin/` I can see it loads the French admin values and when I visit `127.0.0.1:8000/nl/admin/` it loads the Dutch ones... I must be doing something wrong.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', 'homepage.views.index', name="homepage"),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^contact/', 'homepage.views.contact_us', name="contact"),
    url(r'^about/', 'homepage.views.about', name="about"),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^jobs/', include(job_urls)),
    url(r'^news/', include(news_urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    url(r'^content/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'homepage.views.content', name="view_content"),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Do you have "translated" ther urls in question?

Comment: please post the corresponding urls.py files.

Comment: I added my urls.py content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `import ugettext_lazy as _` in your models.py and forms.py, instead of the regular `ugettext`. `ugettext` will evaluate the translations during import, at which point it has no other choice than to use the default language; `ugettext_lazy` will evaluate when rendering, at which point it has the correct language information available.